# Intern console reported doesnt group the different suite

Tags: javascript, frontend, intern

When running the intern client with console reporter, the report output doesnt show any suite grouping if the script to be tested is not being located under an app folder.

**Intern Config:**

```
// Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
suites: [ 'tests/unit/hello' ],
```

**Unit Test:**

```
 define(function (require) {
        var registerSuite = require('intern!object');
        var assert = require('intern/chai!assert');
        var hello = require('../../../Source/MyProject/dist/hello'); // "app/hello" would show suite grouping in the console output

        registerSuite({
            name: 'hello',

            greet: function () {
                assert.strictEqual(hello.greet('Hussein'), 'Hello, Hussein!',
                    'hello.greet should return a greeting for the person named in the first argument');
            }
        });
    });
```

**Console Reporter output:**

[image]

**Expected Reported output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ascending above the module ID root using relative module IDs like this isn’t allowed. The result of this operation is undefined:

```
// from `tests/unit/hello`, this relative module ID
// resolves to "../Source/MyProject/dist/hello", which is
// not valid
var hello = require('../../../Source/MyProject/dist/hello');
```

Instead, you should do the following:

1. Ensure your [`basePath`](http://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-basePath) is configured to point to a directory containing *all* the modules you are going to load.
2. To avoid having to move around your files, set up `loaderOptions.packages` entries.
3. Change your illegal relative module ID to a valid absolute module ID.

This would look something like this (you did not provide your exact directory structure so I am guessing some things):

```
// intern config
{
  basePath: '/path/to/root',
  loaderOptions: {
    packages: [
      { name: 'tests', location: 'tests' },
      { name: 'app', location: 'Source/MyProject/dist' }
    }
  }
}

// tests/unit/hello.js
...
var hello = require('app/hello');
...
```

Note that the final coverage output will display filenames, not module IDs, because code coverage reporting works on the physical file level, not the logical module level.

Also note this is not the only way to solve the problem, but is one relatively straight-forward way to do it.